# Can I apply for a Greece Schengen visa while my current visa is valid, assuming I don't overlap the visa dates?

Tags: visas, schengen, greece

I have a Schengen visa issued by Greece, which will expire in December of this year.

Can I apply for a new one now, even while my visa is still valid? I just want to anticipate the timing. Do I apply with the same requirements?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible as long as the visa dates don't overlap. E.g. if your visa is valid until December 31st, you should apply for a new visa starting on January 1st. The *[Handbook for the processing of visa applications and the modification of issued visas](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf)* mentions:

> ***Example:*** A Moroccan lawyer representing a gender equality NGO who frequently 
>   participates in meetings in various Member States holds a multiple-entry-visa which expires 
>   on 31.5. She applies for a new visa on 15.4.
>
> If a new visa is issued, it should be valid from 1.6. and in such a case the visa holder would be entitled to enter the territory of the Member States on the basis of the first visa that will expire during the stay and leave on the basis of the new visa.

The requirements for applying for a new visa will be the same as for your previous one, although you might qualify for a multi-entry visa depending on your previous travel history.

Comment: I suspect the OP already has a multiple-entry visa.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, if your trip starts in three months or less. Assuming you have a multiple-entry visa valid for more than six months, you can even apply up to three months before the expiry date of your current visa (as opposed to three months before your next trip). This stems from article 9 of the [Schengen visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412):

> Applications shall be lodged no more than three months before the start of the intended visit. Holders of a multiple-entry visa may lodge the application before the expiry of the visa valid for a period of at least six months.

Comment: That's not how I read that provision.  To me, it says that the application shall be lodged no more than three months before a certain date.  Normally, that certain date is the start of the intended visit.  If, however, you have a multiple-entry visa valid for a period of at least six months, the certain date becomes the expiry date of the current visa - but you still may only apply three months before that certain date.  I could definitely be wrong, but that's how it reads to me.

Comment: @MadHatter What do you make of the "for a period of at least six months" at the end, then?

Comment: As I said, if you have a multiple-entry visa **valid for a period of at least six months**, the certain date (which you may apply up to three months before) is now the expiry date of that visa.  If it helps, I read that last sentence as *Holders of a multiple-entry visa may lodge the application before the expiry of the visa-valid-for-a-period-of-at-least-six-months*.

Comment: @MadHatter OK, I get it. I find the phrasing very bad (IMO, it should read “Holders of a multiple-entry visa valid for a period of at least six months […]”) but I just checked the French and German version and they show unambiguously that your interpretation is the right one. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: *I find the phrasing very bad* me too, I assure you!  Glad that between us we puzzled it out.